# php DateTime diff consider only Y-m-d format

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

In mysql db I've a timestamp field (dateexp) defined in my t1 table.
with a query I consider only format Y-m-d of timestamp to find records. Use curdate() instead of now()

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE dateexp < currdate()
```

I would like to do the same thing with php using DateTime class for find a number of days until a date 
but I can't understand how I could do it comparing only the Y-m-d format.

I tried in this way but I use Y-m-d H:i:s format.

```
$row['dateexp'] = "2013-11-10 12:00:00";

$d1 = new DateTime();
$d2 = new DateTime($row['dateexp']);
$interval = $d1->diff($d2);
$days = $interval->format('%r%a');
```

How could I do this for comparing only Y-m-d? I tried with DateTime::createFromFormat but probably in wrong way..

Thanks

Comment: Please, clarify what do you mean 'only dates'. So you need to create `DateTime` object only with date part? Or find a difference in days (so time part matters)?

Comment: I'd like to find diff of 2 dates with format Y-m-d (2013-11-05) and not with format Y-m-d H:i:s (2103-11-05 11:00:00). hours, min and sec affect the result depending on whether the time is before or after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several possible ways to do this. First, you can select date string in desired format from DBMS:

```
SELECT *, DATE(dateexp) AS date_holder FROM t1 WHERE dateexp < currdate()
```

and then apply it in your `DateTime` object:

```
$d1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$d2 = new DateTime($row['date_holder']);
$interval = $d1->diff($d2);
$days = $interval->format('%r%a');
```

Second - you can, as you've mentioned, create `DateTime` from format:

```
$d1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$d2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['dateexp'])));
$interval = $d1->diff($d2);
$days = $interval->format('%r%a');
```

-so you'll be able to avoid selection of additional field in DBMS

Answer (score 0):

## PHP

Don't mix `date()` and `strtotime()` functions with [DateTime extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

You can just create DateTime object with keyword `today` to set today date without time, or use [`DateTime::setTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) on DateTime object, to set time you wish:

```php
$d1 = new DateTime('today');
$d2 = new DateTime($row['dateexp']);
$d2->setTime(0, 0);
echo $d1->diff($d2)->format('%r%a');
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/60970)**.

---

## MySQL

Or you can already calculate days difference in the MySQL, with function [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CURDATE(), DATE('2013-11-10 12:00:00'))
```

or in your case:

```sql
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CURDATE(), DATE(dateexp)) AS diff_in_days
FROM t1 
WHERE dateexp < CURDATE()
```